# ¿Qué NOMBRE se le da al típico algoritmo para generar NÚMEROS RANDOM?

Tags: javascript, algoritmos, random, formulas

Por ejemplo en JavaScript para generar un número random sería:

```
var random_desde_a_hasta_b = Math.round(Math.random() * (b - a + 1) + a)
```

¿Algún nombre oficial para este algoritmo?
¿Existen otros?

*Edit: No un nombre para darle a la función, sino el nombre con el que la comunidad conoce al algoritmo*

**Gracias de antemano**

Comment: El que tu le asignes es válido, mientras el nombre sea claro y entendible, no veo que encuentres una respuesta única al respecto

Comment: El nombre escogelo tu, que sea corto y claro. Ejemplo: rand() o numb(). Como quieras

Answer (score 1):

El algoritmo para `Math.random()` no está especificado por **ECMAscript**, cada implementación elije o hace el que quiere, uno popular es el [xorshift128+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) que entiendo es el que usa [V8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/ceade6cf239e0773213d53d55c36b19231c820b5/src/js/math.js#L143) en estos momentos.

Algunas aclaraciones:

- algoritmicamente no se puede generar números realmente `random`, por eso lo que hacen realmente los lenguajes es usar algoritmos en los que el retorno siga la misma distrubución teórica que los números aleatorios ([distrubución continua](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_uniforme_continua)).
- Hay muchas formas de lograr esto, por eso lo que se toma en consideración es obviamente el mejor desempeño.
- Para el que esté interesado, este artículo (en inglés) aclara algunas cosas https://v8.dev/blog/math-random?showComment=1450389868643#c2004131565745698275